# Discord API returns 400 Bad request when i try fetch but the same request works in postman. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, rest, discord, fetch-api

This is the fetch code in node V18:

```js
let response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/${guild_id}/members/${user_id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "authorization": `Bot ${bot_token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
        }),
    });
```

I am getting 400 Bad request in return but in postman i get 204 empty response (expected result)

**Fetch response**
[image: fetch response]
[image: Fetch response smaller]
**Postman settings**
[image: postman body]
[image: Postman header]
[image: Response]

Related resource: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member

I have tried removing the body also resulting in 400 bad request. If i remove header i get 401 unauthorized. I have tried hardcoding values that work in postman but that also results in 400 bad request.

What i expect to happen is to get 204 no content or 201 with a guild member in the body.

Comment: There is a chance that your request is being rejected by your server due to it being unauthorized. Try using `axios` package to make this request and pass `rejectUnauthorized: false` in your options object and see if it works. `node-fetch` doesn't technically support this header option but you can check this post out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061143/using-rejectunauthorized-with-node-fetch-in-node-js] if you want to give it a try using `node-fetch`

Comment: @deep206 I got it working. If I removed header, it would return 401 unauthorized. But I just copied postmans code snippet and adjusted my fetch based on that, now it is working as intended.

Comment: The only change I see in your answer is in your body where you added `nick`, which according to Discord's documentation is user's nickname. Although, that is an optional parameter. So it is interesting that you got it to work with basically no change. Did you update your `bot_token` or `access_token` to mirror it to your Postman's call?

Comment: Can you please add the postman generated curl that worked to you question. You will find it under "</>" on the right hand side in postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using the following code:

```js
let response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/${guild_id}/members/${user_id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bot ${bot_token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            nick: nick
        }),
    });
```

I have no idea how or why this now suddenly works but ok :)